# Why when I call "GenerateTokenForNewConversationAsync" sometimes it returns null?

Tags: botframework, direct-line-botframework

I am using "Microsoft.Bot.Connector.DirectLine" library to make a DirectLine conversation with my bot. When I try to generate a token to start a conversation using the "GenerateTokenForNewConversationAsync" method, it sometimes  returns null, but other times it works fine.

- I have tried passing the DirectLine App Service endpoint to DirectLineClient, which always works fine, but finally I can not use it since Linux Azure App Service does not supports DirectLine App Service.
- I have regenerated the DirectLine Secret, but after 2 or 3 requests it fails again.

My code is:

```
var tokenResponse = await new DirectLineClient(directLineSecret).Tokens.GenerateTokenForNewConversationAsync();

            // Use token to create conversation
            var directLineClient = new DirectLineClient(tokenResponse.Token);
            var conversation = await directLineClient.Conversations.StartConversationAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because that particular package is quite old and hasn't been updated since 2017 (as per the [NuGet listing](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bot.Connector.DirectLine#:%7E:text=Last%20updated%205/10/2017)) while Direct Line itself has been continuously updated over that time.

As there is no newer package currently available, the most up-to-date method would be to use direct REST calls to communicate with Direct Line.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I just did the test with REST calls, and the same thing still happens. I have tried it too with Postman, and the response is: 
Status: 403 Forbidden
{
    "error": {
        "code": "BadArgument",
        "message": "Site missing. Learn more about sites  https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-connect-directline?view=azure-bot-service-4.0#add-new-site."
    }
}

Comment: Have you enabled the Direct Line channel (which enables the site) in your Azure Bot resource, and are you using the key from it? It is not the same key as App Service Extension.

Comment: Yes, it is enabled. I even tried creating another site, but it fails sometimes again. I have a console application to test my bot which is on Azure App Service. The funny thing is that when it failed me, I passed the code to a colleague and it worked for her. Could directline ban the ip when requesting new tokens?

Comment: On a technical level it's possible, but I have never heard of that happening before.